# How To Keep LG Lancet POWERED OFF While Charging

Tags: lg, verizon

My brand new Verizon LG Lancet that just came in the mail will not stay powered off while on the charger. I want the phone to stay off while charging. How do I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in and then turning it off while it's plugged in?